# save multiple form in one button only

Tags: php

I want to create a project that save the fill up forms in previous form and insert into database using one button only.  For example answer1.php and answer2.php the save button is in the answer2.php i want to fetch data from answer1.php and save to databse same as in answer2.php

this code below insert data in one form only

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT into holiday (holiday_no,holiday_name, status,campaign_name,holiday_type,  createdBy, holiday_date, createdDate)
VALUES('$holiday_no', '$id','$status','$campaign_name','$hol', 'System','$date','$createdDate')") or die(mysql_error());

echo "Data has been saved with holiday name";
```

Comment: Can you just have one php file, and use an "if" statement depending on certain criteria, and then write to the db with the same query? I'm not sure I'm understanding the situation.

Comment: I don't understand either. Can you be more precise what you're aiming to do?

Comment: I just want to save more than one form in database .

Comment: @Mike need to submit several separate forms from a page with one click of a single submit button

Comment: different action url for both form?

Comment: i have a problem regarding to my proj that i was working... 
this is the prob.. in my application form there are so many categories to be fill up... i realize that if i will put all the categories in one form the user will scroll it down untill he/she fills up all the information... 
the alternative solution is i have to cut the form category by category... to avaoid scrolling.. the problem is i dont know how to create a code to handle the data in all the categories before the user will click submit button and all the info typed by user will save on the database.

Comment: Can you post your php code? Just a tip: Why don't you use a category hidden field on each page, though I don't see a category field in your sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're asking for ...but giving it a try ;-) :
You can put the key-value pairs the first script receives into the next form so they get transmitted once again to the second script. E.g. if in the first step something like `category=foo` and `country=bar` gets transmitted write out a form that looks like

```
<form method="POST" action="answer2.php">
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="category" value="foo" />
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="country" value="bar" />
    <!-- all the other things you want to add to the form -->
    <input type="submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

But keep in mind that a) you need to encode the values properly for html output, otherwise your scripts are vulnerable for injection attacks, see http://docs.php.net/htmlspecialchars
and b) your second script can't "be sure" that the values haven't been altered or even transmitted to the first script at all; if you need that (e.g. for some transaction mechanism) you need something else like e.g. http://docs.php.net/features.sessions

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden fields, a session, or a temporary table.

```
<?php

if (empty($_REQUEST)) {
    echo '<form action="', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '">

</form>';
} elseif (empty($_REQUEST['some_field_from_your_second_form']) {
    // Do the second part of your form
} else {
    // Do the final submission
    // Sanitize the values
    // Insert in the database
}
```